# Exclude a specific network from the tc rules

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, network-interface, tc

Even though there are numerous resources on how to create and manipulate traffic control settings using the `tc` command on Linux, I can't find anything useful around network exclusion in `tc`. I would like to apply certain rules to an network interface(i.e., eth0) but exclude a specific network from those rules. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: tc rules are always applied to a given interface. If you want your rules to apply to specific flows, or to exclude specific flows, you might want to filter your traffic with one of the available classifiers. The one you need probably depends on the kind of traffic you deal with, but try `man tc-u32` or, ultimately, `man tc-bpf`.